How to find the percentage change of two graphs
I have two graphs and would like to find the difference between them in percentage.
First I converted them into lists:
Graph_1=[3843.788185, 3734.256494, 3572.574207, 3420.958554, 3254.79344, 3008.104688, 2804.140772, 2630.084873, 2455.295009, 2324.022285, 2159.982356, 2052.704012, 1997.796418, 1919.717952, 1891.275495, 1887.750553, 1882.098642, 1907.227429, 1900.963964, 1869.716515]
Graph_2= [5825.787588, 5712.159078, 5463.242265, 5310.681583, 5174.471092, 4978.994489, 5134.328055, 5040.945936, 4591.175423, 4001.873071, 4030.536351, 4178.250614, 4132.22026, 4028.463262, 4000.654956, 4123.892956, 4106.260715, 4118.031442, 4116.180353, 4124.077156]
I do not need to know if they have common values, only how close they are together.
I tried this:
res = len(set(Graph_1) and set(Graph_2)) / float(len(set(Graph_1) or set(Graph_2))) * 100
print("Percentage similarity among graphs is : " + str(res))

First of all, you should check whenever the two graphs have the same amount of data (length of the lists)
Then I think what you want to achieve is something like that:
percentage_differences = []
for val1, val2 in zip(Graph_1, Graph_2):
    difference = abs(val1 - val2)
    percentage_difference = (difference / val1) * 100
    percentage_differences.append(percentage_difference)

average_percentage_difference = sum(percentage_differences) / len(percentage_differences)

You can then print the value as you like.

They do have the same length. What does this average percentage difference shows?

The code compares each value from two lists (which are the graphs) by calculating the percentage difference for each pair. In the end, the average of these percentage differences is computed.
